# How to load a block of code conditionally using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, blogs

I have a single installation of Wordpress that is powering two domain names. To put it very simply, Site A has four static pages, and Site B has four static pages, but they both *share* a common blog-posts page.

Site A should have a navbar at the top that points to the other Site A pages and Site B should have a navbar that points to the other Site B pages.

Since they (necessarily) share a common WordPress theme, in the `header.php` file I would like to put a PHP `if` statement for a block of code that is the Site A nav and another for the Site B nav. But I'm not sure what condition to actually check for. Is there some way I can cause some pages to identify themselves to PHP as belonging to Site A, and others to Site B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set variables in both sites before the header call, then use an if statement to show the right navigation.

**Site A**

```
<?
$site = 'A';
require('header.php');
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<?
if($site == 'A') {
  //Site A nav
} else {
  //Site B nav
}
?>
```

However, if your two sites have different domain names, you could look at the `$_SERVER` global and key off of that directly in your `header.php` instead.

Comment: This approach increases coupling between the header and the pages that included it, but unfortunately, it's the only 100% reliable way to do this that I know of. Checking variables in $_SERVER as others suggest can be fraught with problems, and even worse, said problems may not manifest immediately.

Comment: Thanks Michael. If that's the case, does it matter where Wordpress is installed? Right now it happens to be in Site A's root folder. I was thinking of simply redirecting Site B's visitors via `.htaccess` but is there a better strategy for this overall?

Comment: If you're setting variables, it shouldn't matter where it's installed. As for strategy, it really only matters on what your end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

If this two websites have different domain name you can validate by doing:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="sitea.com"){
   //code for site a
} else {
   //code for site b
}
```

Comment: If that's the case, does it matter where Wordpress is installed? Right now it happens to be in Site A's root folder. I was thinking of simply  redirecting Site B's visitors via `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=="www.whatever.com") {
//show site a header
}
```